# ReactJS Disable dragging outside the selected day in Full Calendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a standard full calendar setup with drag and drop Interaction plugin. My question is how do I Handle the drag and drop selection, and handle the touch events on mobile devices. I could not find anything helpful in the full calendar documentation. Most importantly, I want to disable dragging outside the selected day, Is it possible to I can write custom functions to handle all this?

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import allLocales from '@fullcalendar/core/locales-all'
import momentTimezonePlugin from '@fullcalendar/moment-timezone'

```
<FullCalendar
            nowIndicator
            plugins={[momentTimezonePlugin, timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
            initialView="timeGridWeek"
            headerToolbar={{
              left: 'prev,next today',
              center: 'title',
              right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay',
            }}
            ref={calendarRef}
            editable
            selectable
            selectMirror
            dayMaxEvents
            weekends
            select={(e) => handleEventAdd(e)}
            eventClick={(e) => handleEventUpdate(e)}
            events={currentevents}
            eventDrop={(e) => handleupdateSchedule(e)}
          />
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventAllow

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/touch